# R object of type 'environment' is not subsettable

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm doing survival analysis with interval censored data and I'm trying to use intcox() function from the incox package to do a Cox regression. I've already done part of the analysis with survfit() and everything worked fine.

When I try to use intcox, there's always a problem:

```
> intcox(Surv(tempo2,tempo1,type="interval2")~dados$sexo)
Error in copy.data[ord, ] : 
  object of type 'environment' is not subsettable

> intcox(Surv(tempo2,tempo1,type="interval2")~sexo, data=dados)
Error in if (any(derivs.wert$g1 <= 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Surv(data$mix, lokal.cens) : Invalid status value, converted to NA
2: In coxph(formula, data) : X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 1
```

dados$sexo is a factor with three levels, and dados is a list with 156 observations and 52 variables. There's no problem when doing a Kaplan-Meier analysis or when using coxph() without interval data. The problem seems to be the same when I use other variable.
I'm using R 3.0.1

**UPDATE**
I didn't change a thing, and now the error looks like this:

```
> intcox(Surv(tempo2,tempo1,type="interval2")~dados$sexo)
Error in intcox(Surv(tempo2, tempo1, type = "interval2") ~ dados$sexo) : 
  Invalid cens status

> intcox(Surv(tempo2,tempo1,type="interval2")~sexo, data=dados)
Error in intcox(Surv(tempo2, tempo1, type = "interval2") ~ sexo, data = dados) : 
  Invalid cens status
```

Comment: I believe your first line's syntax is invalid.  In the second version, it's odds-on that the `NA` that `Surv` returned is what causes your error message. And if that's because you have a singular matrix (second warning), then you're using a tool which is incompatible with your dataset.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I'm almost sure both versions mean the same. And if I run **Surv(tempo2,tempo1,type="interval2")** alone, the result it's the expected (a Surv object). The only possibility I assume may be the error source is that I've mixed censored data(right-censored, interval censored and non-censored) and the documentation does not refer this situation, although it says that accept Surv objects of interval2 type.

Answer (score 1):

1. For your first problem,

   ```
   >intcox(Surv(tempo2,tempo1,type="interval2")~sexo, data=dados)
   Error in if (any(derivs.wert$g1 <= 0)) { : 
   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
   In addition: Warning messages:
   1: In Surv(data$mix, lokal.cens) : Invalid status value, converted to NA
   2: In coxph(formula, data) : X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 1
   ```

it is caused by the fact that you have variables which are linear combinations of other variables in your data frame, which make the X matrix non-singular, as the second warning suggests.

The coxph can deal with this non-singular problem by setting the coefficients of those variables to NA. However, this intcox package is not very robust, unfortunately. One solution is to first find out those variables using some linear model and eliminate them from the data frame. Then off you go.

2. For your second problem,

   ```
   > intcox(Surv(tempo2,tempo1,type="interval2")~sexo, data=dados)
   Error in intcox(Surv(tempo2, tempo1, type = "interval2") ~ sexo, data = dados) : 
     Invalid cens status
   ```

probably you did not formulate your dataset in the right way. I cannot be more helpful, as you have not provided more information about the meaning of the variables tempo1 and tempo2.